# Signing up with Google + Terms of Use checkbox

Tags: usability, user-expectation, signup-signon

I'm stumped: How do you nicely solve the requirement of explicitly checking the "I accept the Terms of Use" checkbox when using single-click sign up with Google / Facebook / Twitter?

Before we had "by signing up you accept our Terms of Service", but lawyers told us that's not good enough and the users have to explicitly agree to terms of use for us to have legal protection.

Looking at it from the user flow perspective, it feels really weird to have (for example) buttons disabled until someone accepts Terms of Service, showing it after signup feels even weirder.

Any of you people seen this solved smoothly?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to disable the call to action:

- Have a checkbox to agree to the T&Cs above the "sign up" buttons.
- If the user skips the T&C checkbox and clicks "sign up", then bring
  up a modal with a link to the T&Cs and the option to "Agree and
  continue" or "go back".

Comment: We're actually thinking about showing the modal on the first login for all users (we have a bunch of old users that need to accept ToS change as well)

Comment: Ah yes, I can see the argument for doing that when it comes to existing users - but isn't it safer to be upfront with new users before they sign up? What if they don't accept the terms? I'm surprised you aren't obligated to gather acceptance of the T&Cs before they register

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for this would be to have your "Accept T&Cs" button where you plan to have your "Sign Up" button. Upon clicking to accept the T&Cs, replace that button with the sign ip button ready to click.

This means that even though the user is having to click twice, you're not moving their focus away from the button and having them have to search the page for the two separate buttons, and they can quickly and easily click a second time to sign up.

This also stops you having to do any validation on the sign up acceptance checkbox as you will know that it has been checked if the user has been able to reach and click the sign up button.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, except we have multiple ways to sign up — Google, Facebook, even email — so I guess that won't work.

Comment: perhaps have the other sign up buttons hidden until the user clicks the I accept the terms of service button and then show all the other buttons once they click it?

Comment: Hiding them altogether wouldn't be as user-friendly. Wouldn't it be better to be able to see what their sign-up options, since it may impact the decision?